# Delete query with inner join executes infinitely

Tags: oracle, inner-join, sql-delete

I am deleting rows from `A` table with the next query:

```
delete from 
  (select A.* from A 
  inner join B 
    on A.id = B.id 
  where B.note = '000000000000')
```

and this query executes infinitely (more than 20 minutes) while select query returns 9300 rows in 3.3 seconds:

```
select * from 
  (select A.* from A 
  inner join B 
    on A.id = B.id 
  where B.note = '000000000000')
```

Where is the problem?

**P.S.:** delete action has taken 40 minutes.

**P.P.S.:** According to ["Which is Most Efficient when Deleting Rows: EXISTS, IN, or a VIEW"](https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/which-is-most-efficient-when-deleting-rows-exists-in-or-a-view/) there is no difference in the described examples.

**UPDATE:** the situation reproduced again with the same symptoms "SELECT is fast, DELETE is slow"

DB-admins checked for blockings and found that there are two sessions are blocking each other, one session is sql-delete statement described above; the other one is not known but I suppose that it could be the same delete statement or another delete statement in related table.

This seems to be true according to Database Locking: [What it is, Why it Matters and What to do About it](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83):

> Oracle’s implementation is to maintain separate versions of the
>   related data blocks. The uncommitted changes made in one transaction
>   are visible within the transaction that made them, while other
>   sessions will see the old, unchanged version. In this way, isolation
>   is maintained and **select statements never block**.

Comment: For one thing, deleting rows takes a lot longer than selecting them - though usually not that long.  For another, maybe the delete is blocked by another transaction - waiting for it to commit or rollback?

Comment: Did the delete finish after 40 minutes, or is it still going?

Comment: @TonyAndrews , after 40 minutes rows were successfully deleted and query completed execution

Comment: Well that's something.  I really don't think the problem here has anything to do with SQL syntax.  9300 rows in 40 minutes is about 4 rows/second.  That is very, very slow but could happen if the table is full of CLOBs/BLOBs, or has many child tables with ON DELETE CASCADE foreign keys, or many indexes, etc.

Comment: @TonyAndrews , seems to be true. "A" table has relation to two other tables. And one relation uses two columns with VARCHAR fields (of 20 & 10 length), another relation is done with NUMBER (length 22)

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko did you solve your problems? did our answers help you?

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu , now I can not reproduce this problem, data is already deleted. But I have already tried IN-query, and it was as slow as JOIN-query, so I can not accept this answer

Comment: Did you make a try creating relations between you tables? as I told you this will create indexes and speed up the process.

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu , as I have told "data is already deleted" (primary task) and this situation is hard to reproduce with previous conditions. Have no time for the task "researches in deletion speed" right now

Comment: @TonyAndrews, the problem was in DB blocking sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple `one session is blocking another` that is why delete operation takes too much time:

```
BLOCKER                           SID 'ISBLOCKING'  BLOCKEE                           SID
------------------------------ ------ ------------- ------------------------------ ------
XXXXXXXXXX                        832  is blocking  XXXXXXXXXX                        124
```

Now it is good to know how to avoid this situation but this is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
delete from A where id in (select id from B where B.note = '000000000000')
```

Comment: that is what I have started with... but the query had not complited during that run

Comment: which kind of relation do you have between table A and B?

Comment: there is no PK-FK relation, in fact just two unrelated tables

Comment: If you are making Joins between 2 tables is a really good practice to have relations between them, it creates an index that speed up the searches and give you nice options like delete on cascade.

Answer (score -1):

Try naming the table you are deleting from:

```
Delete from A where exists (select...)
```